# how to realize which context menu is called

Tags: android, android-listview, viewflipper, onlongclicklistener, android-contextmenu

I have a view flipper with two listviews inside. I have registered onLongLickListener to both of the listViews. I can get the position etc of the item when I press something on contextmenu, but I cannot get which listView owns the current menu. if needed, I can provide some codes, thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Called these two in onCreate

```
listView1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            selected_list = 1;
            return false;
        }

    });
    listView2.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            selected_list = 2;
            return false;
        }

    });
```

that worked and used this way:

```
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();

    if(selected_list==1){
           //do something.
    }else if(selected_list==2){
           //do o/w
    }
 }
```